# Issue with size of CCsprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

im testing my game on iphone5 simulator

i have background sprite with 1136*640 pixels size image

if i set my background with,

```
background1.anchorPoint=CGPointZero;

background1.position=ccp(0,0);
```

cocos2d magnifies that image.

if i set my background with,

```
background1.anchorPoint=CGPointZero;

background1.position=ccp(0,0); 

background1.scale=0.5;
```

image fits screen, which is perfect. but if i do so then i get wrong `background.contentSize` , is that magnification of sprite stoppable?

i'v also set `[director enableRetinaDisplay:NO];`

Comment: you **must** enable retina support and provide retina assets if you want your app approved by apple!

Comment: oh..thanks a lot to make me aware..

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you haven't named the sprite with the `-widehd` extension. Like: `background-widehd.png` OR `-iphone5hd` depending on your version of cocos2d. If you targeting retina displays you should:

> [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES]

Comment: no luck, i set [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] and background-hd.png..

still no change

Comment: strange. Have you read this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:how_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Comment: Ah, you should use -iphone5hd or -widehd for the iPhone5. Sorry, I read your question a bit to fast. Updating my answer.

Comment: i put, if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

and it actually prints CCLog!!.. means ratina is not supported..then what is need of scaling image!?

Comment: And in the simulator you've set Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina 4-inch)?

Comment: oh one min, im using xcode 4.2 and mac 10.6.8.. is this sufficient?? ...i guess things need to be upgraded!